# import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, import, android-gradle-plugin

Import kotlinx greyed out

[image]

I think i try nearly everything. Reinstall Android Studio, Invalide Cache, new Project same Problem.

i just can't find the Solution

Comment: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/377

Comment: did you convert your project to androidx? To me the issue happened after that.

Comment: kotlin-android-extensions is not supported anymore use [viewbinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Can you try

- File | Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Deleting .idea folder
- Clean
- Re-import the project

**OR** just remove `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` , sync gradle plugin and then I added it again.

Comment: i add it to my file but its greyed out and its says "Unused import directive"

Comment: Did you try running your app? unused simply mean, it is not used yet, it will be used when you use some id in your class.

Comment: that verry weird the import line Disappears when i try to add a id to my class

Comment: Thank you so much, i dont know how but now its working

Comment: Deleting .idea folder worked for me, I think it started happening because I switch branched and AS didn't know how to go from there

Comment: My project compiled, but an IDEA showed an error, I just removed the `kotlin-android-extensions`  -> sync, and added it again and it worked again

Answer (score 153):

Check "build.gradle(:app)" file,

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

if kotlin extension is missing, add `kotlin-android-extensions` as shown below and click on "Sync now"

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Comment: This worked. I think there is a bug on the new Android Studio 4.1 version that excludes extension at project creation.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks

Comment: This was my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Simple solution, thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Just add below line in your build.gradle(Module:YourProjectName.app) inside the plugins section on top:

```
plugins{
       id 'com.android.application'
       id 'kotlin-android'
       id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

Mostly first two lines are already there just need to add 3rd one and sync project

Answer (score 15):

***Here is a step by step answer:***

- From right side of the Android studio click on `Gradle`
- Right click on the app and click `Open Gradle Config`
- New source opening in `plugins` part and then add this:

`id 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

- Tap `sync`

**Result:** now you can import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Answer (score 10):

```
module gradle

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

dependencies {
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

project gradle

buildscript{
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.11'
}
 dependencies {
  classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: The answer is worked for me (apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions') & after Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 9):

Synthetics are now deprecated from Google. Try to avoid using them as it might lead to null pointer exceptions and unexpected behaviour on your app.

Read more on:

[Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) from official developers site.

Answer (score 5):

In `build.gradle (:app)`, add:

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
```

In `MainActivity`:

```kotlin
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
```

Modify `onCreate`:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setListeners()
    }
```

To set listeners:

```kotlin
    /**
     * Attaches listeners to all the views.
     */
    private fun setListeners() {
        val clickableViews: List<View> =
            listOf(
                binding.view1,
                binding.view2,
                // ...
            )
        for (item in clickableViews) {
            item.setOnClickListener { ... }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Kotlin Android Extensions is depreciated. Migrate to Jetpack view binding. See below:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Answer (score 1):

For me it was just adding the `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` to app's build.gradle, press sync gradle files and i was able to get **synthetics**

Answer (score 1):

For newcomers to Android world who use JetPack Library:

> Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported. If your app uses Kotlin synthetics for view binding, use this guide to migrate to Jetpack view binding.
> If your app doesn't already use Kotlin synthetics for view binding, see View binding for basic usage information.

From [Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)

To insert plugins in `app:build.gradle` as

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

isn't necessary anymore and does not work.

### STEP 1.

Instead you must insert this implementation in the `app:build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

Examples: [Setup instruction by developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), [Sean McQuillan's Blog setup instruction in Android 3.6 and Android 4.0](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc), [Github ViewBindingSample given by developer.android.com](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/ViewBindingSample/app/build.gradle)

### STEP 2

To bind the `.xml` layout to the main activity program (ex: `MainActivity.kt`) you must proceed like the following in the acitivity `.kt` file :

```
private lateinit var binding: ResultProfileBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    binding.labelWeight.text = "weight (lbs)" // a TextView in the layout
}
```

> If you have a layout called activity_awesome.xml, which contains a
> button and two text views, view binding generates a small class called
> ActivityAwesomeBinding that contains a property for every view with an
> ID in the layout.

From [McQuillan's blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/use-view-binding-to-replace-findviewbyid-c83942471fc)

So here `ResultProfileBinding` is the id binding of the layout `result_profile_binfind.xml`. Snake case is converted to Pascal case for `.xml` layout name, and Camel case for views present in the `.xml` layout (ex: `TextView android:id="@+id/label_weight` in the layout will give `binding.labelWeight` in the activity program) .

Answer (score 0):

Simple friend, you forgot the asterisk.

```
    import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

It just happened to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'kotlin-android'
```

remove plugins and added them two of them.
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
id 'kotlin-android'

should be added. restart the project.

So the problem as I have found is in gradle plugins, then you need to restart, rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help... maybe is related with the new way to get views from layouts

Kotlin:

1. open gradle app.module and add this line inside

   android{

   ```
    android{viewBinding.enabled = true
    ...

    }
   ```

(then sync)

2. go to MainActivity.kt and do this:

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) // 2.1

setContentView(binding.root) // 2.2 instead of (R.layout.activity_main)

now views are called this way

```
binding.btn1.setOnClickListener{...}
```

or

```
binding.txtviewTitle.text = "Welcome to the jungle" // or any R.string
```

note: after you sync the gradle module.app with the line you will find any activity with the same name+Binding

Look 2.1 reference

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem in this manner:
in build.gradle and in plugins add id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
after some seconds when I write the name of button, automatically
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
imported to code

Answer (score 0):

as android document says Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported.
If your app uses Kotlin synthetics for view binding, use this guide to migrate to Jetpack view binding.
[Migrate from Kotlin synthetics to Jetpack view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration#:%7E:text=Kotlin%20Android%20Extensions%20is%20deprecated,migrate%20to%20Jetpack%20view%20binding.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was missing  in module's gradle file:

```
androidExtensions {
  experimental = true 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i applied all above solutions but didn't work and then i just added following line in menifest and it is working fine.

package="com.your.package"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
   package="com.your.package"
    >
```

Answer (score -1):

this fixed it for me :

1. Put this into your app.iml

`<facet type="kotlin-language" name="Kotlin"> <configuration version="3" platform="JVM 1.8" allPlatforms="JVM [1.8]" useProjectSettings="false"> <compilerSettings /> <compilerArguments> <option name="jvmTarget" value="1.8" /> <option name="pluginOptions"> <array> <option value="plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:enabled=true" /> <option value="plugin:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:defaultCacheImplementation=hashMap" /> </array> </option> </compilerArguments> </configuration> </facet>`

2. Do gradle sync