# Unresolved reference in Android Studio problem

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new in using Android Studio. I used this because our professor wants us to make an application. I am following the tutorial on YouTube step by step and I know that I did everything he did on the video. But why am i having this error `Unresolved reference: nextActivity`?

Here is the code in MainActivity.kt

```
package com.willitpush.app

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        nextActivity.setOnClickListener{

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code on activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#2196F3"
        android:text="play"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see there should be no error because I typed in the same id. but why am I having error on this line? `nextActivity.setOnClickListener`. Sorry I am just new in Android Studio.

Comment: Probably you missed step about `plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Comment: @StanislavBondar there's no step doing that but how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity\_main is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52271521/import-kotlinx-android-synthetic-main-activity-main-is-not-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unresolved reference` means you're referring to something that doesn't exist, like an undeclared variable name - or at least the compiler doesn't know about it, from the code that you have. `nextActivity` isn't declared in your code anywhere, so the compiler is saying "ok, what's this?"

What Stanislav is showing you is the plugin that enables "Kotlin synthetic binding", which is basically magic code that turns your declared IDs in the layout XML file (like `android:id="@+id/nextActivity"` in your `Button`) into a variable in your `Activity` class with the same name as the ID. So even though you haven't declared a `val nextActivity: Button` anywhere, the synthetics have added it, so you can refer to it like in your example. Without synthetics, it won't work.

Don't worry about not understanding all that, this kind of magic is great when you know it's there and how it works, it's incredibly confusing for a beginner. The normal way to look up a `Button` (or any `View`) is to do

```
val nextActivity = findViewById<Button>(R.id.nextActivity)
```

Kotlin synthetics are deprecated now, you're meant to use the `ViewBinding` library instead. Honestly, I'd use `findViewById` if you're new so that you get used to the general idea of things - you'll learn a lot! You can use the fancy automation later